# How do i set event handler to a control?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-8

I am new to windows 8 app development using xaml and c#. I created a new image using.

```
  Image img = new Image();
```

I successfully added the image to the canvas, but i want to add an eventhandler pointerpressed to the img. How do i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your **Image** instance in code

```
Image img = new Image();
```

And I'm presuming you've added it to your **Canvas** also in code, so the logical place to hook your event in code

```
Image img = new Image();
img.PointerPressed += Image_PointerPressed;
```

Where you have defined the **Image_PointerPressed** elsewhere in that same class

```
private void Image_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // do what you want here...
}
```

Comment: Should really be another post, but I think what you want is img.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.All;